# Parallax effect with Swift - Device 6

Tags: ios, swift, parallax

[enter link description here][1]The iOS app Device 6 has really left a mark on me, and as a iOS developer, I am confused as to how the app was created.

Does anyone know how they were able to create parallax scrolling with non-interative text all around the image?

Here's a link demoing the app, in about 16 seconds into the video, you can see the parallax scrolling. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VdeB9_q9nU

P.S. for anyone confused, basically I created a label with a few lines of text. Now underneath that label, I want to place a box that's 2x2 inches. Inside that box should be a image, and as the user scrolls down, the image  inside the box should scroll down too, just at a different speed. I have no idea how to do that! For a visual interpretation, just see the video link I posted above.

Comment: Please post a short movie-clip demonstrating the effect you want to re-create, I don't think you will get many answers if we have to buy an app just to see what you are after ;)

Comment: Just did! here's the link (the parallax comes 16 seconds into the video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VdeB9_q9nU

Comment: "Does anyone know" Anyone who knows (i.e. works for the company) won't tell you, so anyone who tells you anything would just be guessing. I have an idea how _I_ would do it, but I have no idea what _they_ are doing.

Comment: So what are you after? The complete game engine, or just how to re-create the parallax effect?

Comment: just the parallax effect. I put in a label with 10 lines of dialogue. Now below that paragraph, I want to insert an squared box, and inside the box should be a image with parallax scrolling. But I don't know how to do that

Comment: The parallax algorithm is universal, we do have a lot of algorithms to describe this kind of effect(also a lot of tutorials, specially in the web front-end area). The great problem in here is to port those algorithms to work with the UIKit views. From my notion, this can be achieved getting the contentOffSet, getting it's growing value with some constant and getting a new value to animate the UIImageView's location inside another view(Container) with clipsToBounds settled to YES. Just a guess, not sure if this would work.

Comment: Are these views embedded in a UIScrollView? So, if yes, you can take the amount the UIScrollView has been moved, and apply that data to a transform within the UIImageView of the image you want the parallax effect on. If you just apply the same offset, the image will scroll twice the speed as the UIScrollView. That value can be divided on some factor so you get another amount of scrolling.